# i want to fetch the sqlite database then according to the date existing in it i want to create a notification.. but the system display an error

Tags: android, sqlite, runtime-error, android-notifications, android-cursor

i have an android application that use sqlite database that contain stored data  one of them is the date.

## sqlite schema

```
- [_id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 - [stad_name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 - [team1] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

  [team2] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  [stage] varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
  [match_date] DATETIME NOT NULL, 
  [flags1] CHAR(255), 
  [flags2] CHAR(255), 
  [group_team] CHAR(1));
```

so what i want is that after i fetching the database i want to create a notification according to that date.. but the system display an error :

## logCat

```
04-29 22:49:32.137: E/AndroidRuntime(2841): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 48 requested, with a size of 48
04-29 22:49:32.137: E/AndroidRuntime(2841):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
04-29 22:49:32.137: E/AndroidRuntime(2841):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
04-29 22:49:32.137: E/AndroidRuntime(2841):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
04-29 22:49:32.137: E/AndroidRuntime(2841):     at com.devleb.expandablelistdemo3.FirstActivity.createBasicNotification(FirstActivity.java:201)
04-29 22:49:32.137: E/AndroidRuntime(2841):     at com.devleb.expandablelistdemo3.FirstActivity.showNotification(FirstActivity.java:186)
04-29 22:49:32.137: E/AndroidRuntime(2841):     at com.devleb.expandablelistdemo3.FirstActivity.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:66)
04-29 22:49:32.137: E/AndroidRuntime(2841):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-29 22:49:32.137: E/AndroidRuntime(2841):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-29 22:49:32.137: E/AndroidRuntime(2841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
04-29 22:49:32.137: E/AndroidRuntime(2841):     ... 11 more
```

how to fix this error and what i am doing wrong ??

## FirstActivity.java

```
package com.devleb.expandablelistdemo3;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private ExternalDbOpenHelper extDB;

    private static final String DB_NAME = "world_cup.db";
    // *****Tables name**************************//
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "match_list";

    // *****Tbale name******************************

    public static final String PLACE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String STAD_NAME = "stad_name";
    public static final String TEAM1 = "team1";
    public static final String TEAM2 = "team2";
    public static final String MATCH_DATE = "match_date";
    public static final String FLAG1 = "flags1";
    public static final String FLAG2 = "flags2";

    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] { PLACE_ID, STAD_NAME,
            TEAM1, TEAM2, MATCH_DATE, FLAG1, FLAG2, };
    // *****Tbale name******************************

    ItemDetails listdetail;

    Cursor c;

    private static final int myNotificationId = 1;

    // private DatabaseHelper dbHelper = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        getDiffDate();

        extDB = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
        database = extDB.openDataBase();

        showNotification();
    }

    public void listTeams(View v) {
        Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    public void listGroups(View v) {
        Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), GroupList.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    public void DisplaySched(View v) {

        Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MatchScheduleList.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void getDiffDate() {

        String dateStop = "06/12/2014 23:00:00";

        // HH converts hour in 24 hours format (0-23), day calculation
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        Date d1 = new Date();

        Date d2 = null;

        try {

            d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

            // in milliseconds
            long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

            long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
            long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
            long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
            long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

            System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
            System.out.print(diffHours + " hours, ");
            System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
            System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds.");

            TextView txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDifDate);
            String resultDate = diffDays + "days " + diffHours + "Hours "
                    + diffMinutes + "Min " + diffSeconds + "S";
            txtDate.setText(resultDate);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;

        c = database.query(true, TABLE_NAME, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        if (c != null) {

            c.moveToFirst();

            while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
                listdetail = new ItemDetails();

                listdetail.setTeam1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("team1")));

                listdetail.setTeam2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("team2")));

                listdetail.setDate_match(c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex("match_date")));

                listdetail.setFlag1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("flags1")));

                listdetail.setFlag2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("flags2")));

                c.moveToNext();

            }

        }
        return c;

    }





    // for the notification


    private PendingIntent preparePendingIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 
                0, 
                intent, 
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return pendingIntent;
    }

    private void showNotification() {
        PendingIntent notificationIntent = preparePendingIntent();
        Notification notification = createBasicNotification(notificationIntent);
        displayNotification(notification);
    }


    private Notification createBasicNotification(PendingIntent notificationIntent) {
        Cursor cursor = getAllRows();


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new Builder(
                getApplicationContext());
        Notification notification = builder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fifa_2014_4)
                .setContentTitle("Up Comming Match")
                .setContentText(
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("match_date"))
                                + (c.getColumnIndex("team1"))
                                + (c.getColumnIndex("team2"))
                                + (c.getColumnIndex("flags1"))
                                + (c.getColumnIndex("flags2"))).build();


        return notification;

    }

    private void displayNotification(Notification notification) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(myNotificationId , notification);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After iterating through the whole cursor with getAllRows()

you try to get one more element:

```
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("match_date"))
                                + (c.getColumnIndex("team1"))
                                + (c.getColumnIndex("team2"))
                                + (c.getColumnIndex("flags1"))
                                + (c.getColumnIndex("flags2"))).build();
```

This won't work. You will have to remove these lines.

try following:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import de.gelbeseiten.androidapp.activities.MainActivity;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private ExternalDbOpenHelper extDB;

    private static final String DB_NAME = "world_cup.db";
    // *****Tables name**************************//
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "match_list";

    // *****Tbale name******************************

    public static final String PLACE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String STAD_NAME = "stad_name";
    public static final String TEAM1 = "team1";
    public static final String TEAM2 = "team2";
    public static final String MATCH_DATE = "match_date";
    public static final String FLAG1 = "flags1";
    public static final String FLAG2 = "flags2";

    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] { PLACE_ID, STAD_NAME,
            TEAM1, TEAM2, MATCH_DATE, FLAG1, FLAG2, };
    // *****Tbale name******************************

    ItemDetails listdetail;

    Cursor c;

    private static final int myNotificationId = 1;

    // private DatabaseHelper dbHelper = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        getDiffDate();

        extDB = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
        database = extDB.openDataBase();

        showNotification();
    }

    public void listTeams(View v) {
        Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    public void listGroups(View v) {
        Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), GroupList.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    public void DisplaySched(View v) {

        Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MatchScheduleList.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isTomorrow(Date d1) {

      GregorianCalendar tomorrow = new GregorianCalendar();
        tomorrow.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        return (d1.before(tomorrow.getTime()));

    }

    public Cursor getAllRows(PendingIntent notificationIntent){
        String where = null;

        c = database.query(true, TABLE_NAME, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        if (c != null) {

            c.moveToFirst();

            while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
                listdetail = new ItemDetails();

                listdetail.setTeam1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("team1")));

                listdetail.setTeam2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("team2")));

                listdetail.setDate_match(c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex("match_date")));

                listdetail.setFlag1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("flags1")));

                listdetail.setFlag2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("flags2")));

                Calendar t = new GregorianCalendar();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY", Locale.getDefault());
                Date dt = null;
                try {
                    dt = sdf.parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("match_Date")));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(isTomorrow(dt)){
                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new Builder(
                            getApplicationContext());
                    Notification notification = builder
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fifa_2014_4)
                            .setContentTitle("Up Comming Match")
                            .setContentText(
                                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("match_date"))
                                            + (c.getColumnIndex("team1"))
                                            + (c.getColumnIndex("team2"))
                                            + (c.getColumnIndex("flags1"))
                                            + (c.getColumnIndex("flags2"))
                            ).build();

                    displayNotification(notification);
                }
                c.moveToNext();

            }

        }
        return c;

    }





    // for the notification


    private PendingIntent preparePendingIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 
                0, 
                intent, 
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return pendingIntent;
    }

    private void showNotification() {
        PendingIntent notificationIntent = preparePendingIntent();
        getAllRows(notificationIntent);

    }



    private void displayNotification(Notification notification) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(myNotificationId , notification);
    }

}
```

Comment: but these are the ContentText if i remove them the notification still work ??

Comment: depends on what you want to do. Do you want to create a notification for each db entry?

Comment: what i want is that let say tomorrow will have an event.  in the sqlite the date of tomorrow is stored so i want after fetching the database to  create a notification to inform the user.  i do not know if i explained my question..hope that you can help me

Comment: you will have to write the where clause depending on the date though, since I dont know your db scheme thats the best I could do

Comment: your suggestion worked there is no error anymore...but the notification did not work it did not display what i want so how to make it work ??

Comment: i will add the database schema  if that what it takes take a look

Comment: now it show the notification but the contentText is the last row in the sqlite database   and do not show neither the names or the images

Comment: okay inserted time-check for you :) I cant do more without having the whole project ;)

Comment: mm no the stored date that is shown in the notification the last record that is not what i want  ... i want to see if the date is 31 4/2014 tomorrow and in the sqlite there is 31/4/2014 i want to create tomorrow a notification.. all what i want is in this activity the second activity is the **sqliteOpenHelper** and the **ItemDetails** classes

Comment: please create a new SO-question with the latest code and the issue you are facing with.

Answer (score 0):

It crashes because you try to access a slot outside of the cursor bounds:

```
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 48 requested, with a size of 48
```

Instead of

```
while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
 [...]
 c.moveToNext();
}
```

use

```
do {
  [...]                 
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```